# Google maps scale control renders as white rectangle

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I made a simple page using google maps to display markers on a map inside a dotNet application. The issue is the scaleControl in the low-right corner. It is rendering as a white rectangle, instead of the expected scale indicator. If I click the white rectangle it becomes a little bigger, as is expected because it is switching between km and miles, only it's not rendering correctly.

```
function Init(lat, lng, zoomLvl) {
  ll = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  zoom = zoomLvl;
  var mO = {
    scaleControl:true,
    zoom:zoom,
    zoomControl:true,
    zoomControlOptions: {style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE},
    center: ll,
    disableDoubleClickZoom:true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mO);
}
```

[image]

If anyone could shed some light on the situation?

Comment: it would be important to see the CSS for this page.