# scaleControl not displaying correctly in .net

Tags: javascript, .net, wpf, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to include a scaleControl on a Google Map running in a WebBrowser control in WPF.

Everything works fine, except when I try to enable the scaleControl. It displays as a white box. (see below)

I am initializing the map as follows:

```
var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 2,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scaleControl: true
        };
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

If you click the white rectangle, it changes size (as expected when changing units). A screenshot of the rectangle is below.

[image]

I believe this issue might be related to the fact I am using the map in a WPF WebBrowser element. As I have seen this issue somewhere else and that was also using WPF.

Any ideas on how to correctly display this scaleControl?

**UPDATE:**

From DormantOden's answer, I have managed to fix my issue and get the ScaleControl to work.

I went into the registry and added the following values:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\"MY APP NAME".exe

&

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\"MY APP NAME".exe

I set the value to 0x2AF7, which according to [DormantOden's link](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version), causes the WebBrowser control to run as IE10 instead of IE7.

The scaleControl now renders correctly

[image]

Comment: I am not alone with this problem: [See Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558580/web-browser-with-googple-map) [and Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710760/google-maps-scale-control-renders-as-white-rectangle)

Comment: I think what @geocodezip might have meant was: If you can post the css used then someone may be able to find the culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is due to the WPF WebBrowser element defaulting to rendering with old versions of IE.

See [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version) on how to specify the IE version used. It will likely fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment, so adding as an answer that I got that white scalebar space when IE 10 (somehow) switched into "Compatability View".  As someone who seldom uses IE I was unaware of that such can occur so it took quite awhile to figure out what the problem was (I was testing some javascript for cross-browser compatability so first thought it was a problem with my code). Switching out of "Compatability View" (i.e. IE 7 mode) gave me the normal scalebar.  So far as I know this has nothing to do with WPF (but I don't really know what WPF is).  Hope this helps someone else who simply experiences this problem when running IE 10.